# Check if an array contains values from object and return them?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array, say something like that:

```js
var array = [{something:"a"},{something:"b"},{something:"c"}]
```

I now want to get the Object which contains `"b"`. How can I do that?

Here's what I tried finding before : I found out `array.filter` and `array.find` with `includes` but I couldn't get a way on how to use it on a String inside *Object* inside an Array and not just strings inside an Array.

Comment: `array.find(x => x.something.includes("b"))` for partial match or `array.find(x => x.something === "b")` for exact match.

Comment: Both `filter` and `find` pass the element into the callback function. The array element is your object, so now all you need to do, is access a specific property of that object. What the example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter does with the `length`, you want to do with `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the object as you asked (In case if it existing)

```
let resultWithSomethingB = array.filter(element => element.something === 'b')[0];
```

Comment: And what if array is empty?

Comment: @nafas the result would be `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought this would throw exception not undefined... I might be wrong!!!

Comment: @nafas filtering an empty array returns an empty array. Getting the first item of an empty array returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array function filter to accomplish this:

```js
var array = [{something:"a"},{something:"b"},{something:"c"}];

// Filter array based on .something
console.log(array.filter(a => { return a.something === "b" }))
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use `array.filter`:

```js
let newObject = null;

const newArray = array.filter(function(item) {
    // Return an item if the something property is a "b"
    return item.something === "b";
});

if (newArray.length > 0) {
    // Returns the first element
    newObject = newArray[0];
}

// Use the newObject
```